# Github Desktop master not updating after merge branch

Tags: github

When I use GitHub Desktop to merge a local branch with the master, everything looks good on the remote version. But the master branch on GitHub Desktop doesn't update. When I click `sync`, I get the following error message:

> project has been updated on https://github.com/user/project.git since
>   you last synced. You can try syncing again or run `git pull origin  master && git push origin master` from the command line.

When I follow the error message instructions, everything is updated properly. But the next time I pull and merge the branches, the same thing occurs.

Any thoughts on what I may have done to cause this and how it can be resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the local master branch has no [upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309).
Next time, when following the instructions, try:

```
git pull origin  master && git push -u origin master
```

The `-u` ensure master has origin/master as its upstream branch.
Then the sync should work.